# How to make bigger the contour integral symbol

Tags: fontsize, resize, integral, contour

Someone knows if the circle of the integral can be bigger?

[image]

Comment: Ìt seems to me that the `\oint`  symbol from `esint` has a slightly bigger circle.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work for me. It breaks all my \ref I have use. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circle is part of the character, like the top of an `8` so the correct answer is that you are supposed to pick a font you like then trust the font designer. However this being TeX there are various circles available that could be abused.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\myoint{\mathop{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(5,3){\circle{7}}\end{picture}{\int}}}
\begin{document}

\[ \oint\limits_C f(z) + \myoint\limits_C f(z)  \]

\end{document}
```